# VBS for excel: Using a script variable in Range selection

Tags: string, excel, dynamic, vbscript, range

I've seen similar questions asked for using VBA in excel, but I'm using VBScript so it's a bit different. The answers to the other questions gave me some clues, but I just don't know how to fix this.

I'm using .SetSourceData to define a range to use in a graph. It works fine to define the range from the first to the last row (whole sheet) but I want to define a dynamic range using a variable defined earlier. So this works:

```
.SetSourceData objWorksheet.Range("E1","F" & LastRow), xlColumns
```

where LastRow is defined as `LastRow=objWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`. Now what I want to do is use a range starting from the last row, going back a few rows. So my thought was to do this:

```
.SetSourceData objWorksheet.Range(Rowstring,"F" & LastRow), xlColumns
```

where RowString is defined as

```
WeekNumber = LastRow - 1000
RowString = "E" & WeekNumber
```

But it gives me an error. How can I use a string variable in a range, and set it as source data for chart generation? Here's the code I'm using

```
    WeekNumber = LastRow - 1000
    RowString = "E" & WeekNumber
    WScript.echo(RowString)


' Data for last week

Sub LastWeek()
    WeekNumber = LastRow - 1000
    RowNumber = LastRow - WeekNumber
    RowString = "E" & RowNumber
End Sub

myrange = "E1:E52"

Set Range1 = objWorksheet.Range(myrange)

' Define chart properties 

Set objChart = objExcel.Charts.Add()
    With objChart
        'define chart type
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        'format chart
        .SeriesCollection(1).Border.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        REM .ChartArea.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .PlotArea.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .HasTitle = True 
        .ChartTitle.Text = "usage"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "test"
        .HasLegend = False
        'define data
        .SetSourceData objWorksheet.Range(RowString,"F" & LastRow), xlColumns
        .Export "Test.png", "PNG"
    End With
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `WeekNumber = LastRow - 1000` , could this lead to a negative `WeekNumber` value?

Comment: Which line is giving you the error? And what error exactly do you get?

Comment: I checked the number, I get a string variable value of "E4414", which I'm now trying to input instead of "E1" or whatever explicit expression I use for the range.

Comment: I get an "Unkonwn runtime error" on the .SetSourceData line, code 800A03EC, Microsoft VBScript runtime error'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.SetSourceData objWorksheet.Range(Rowstring,"F" & LastRow), xlColumns
```

where

```
WeekNumber = LastRow - 1000
RowString = "E" & WeekNumber
```

gives

```
...Range("E4414","F" & LastRow)...
```

and I think you are most likely after

```
...Range("E4414:F" & LastRow)...
```

so you need to replace the `,` *comma* with a `:` *semicolon*

rebuild your `RowString` variable like this

```
RowString = "E" & weekNumber & ":"
```

and the entire statement

```
.SetSourceData objWorksheet.Range(Rowstring & "F" & LastRow), xlColumns

' PlotBy:=xlColumns for VBA
```