# Errors when clear variable Excel range using VBS

Tags: excel, vbscript, named-ranges, vba

I have a VBS script that copies an existing sheet and I need to clear a dynamic range of cells (depends on the particular excel workbook opened)

I am able to clear the range when it is hard coded:

```
Set xl                      = CreateObject("Excel.application")
fso.CopyFile strFileSelect, fso.GetParentFolderName(strFileSelect) & "\Newversion.xlsm"

wshShell.Run """" & fso.GetParentFolderName(strFileSelect) & "\Newversion.xlsm"""

xl.Application.Sheets("Auto").Range("E15:BP142").ClearContents
```

but get errors when I try

```
xl.Application.Sheets("Auto").Range(Cells(15, 5), Cells(142, 67)).ClearContents
```

Actually, I ultimately want to clear the range based on UBound of two arrays for the Range, something like:

```
xl.Application.Sheets("Auto").Range("E15", .Cells((UBound(ArrayText)+1), (((UBound(ArrayStepText) + 1) * 2) + 5))).ClearContents
```

I have tried also using cells instead of .cells, tried

```
set r = Range("E15", Cells(142,67))
```

and clearing r, that does not work either.

I also can't use xlUp or something like that as there are hidden and protected cells after my array range

There is a similar question

[VBS for excel: Using a script variable in Range selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331035/vbs-for-excel-using-a-script-variable-in-range-selection)

but I cannot use the rebuilding of the string as I don't know the column letter that it ends with and would have to make a look-up table to determine the column letters from the UBound of the array and that number could go to 128.

Surely there is an easier/ more efficient way?

Thanks

Comment: You're using the global `Cells` and `Range` objects.  Get a reference to the worksheet and use fully qualified references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comintern:

```
endRow    =    UBound(ArrayCriteria) + 14
endColumn =    UBound(ArrayText) + 4
xl.Range(xl.Application.Sheets("Auto").Cells(15,5),xl.Application.Sheets("Auto").Cells(endRow,endColumn).clearContents
```

Specify as an Excel range, then specify that the range starts in the excel application with full qualification

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (untested):

```
newPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(strFileSelect) & "\Newversion.xlsm"
fso.CopyFile strFileSelect, newPath

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
set wb = xl.Workbooks.open(newPath)
set sht = wb.Sheets("Auto")

set rng = sht.Range(sht.Range("E15"), _
          sht.Cells((UBound(ArrayText)+1), _
          (((UBound(ArrayStepText) + 1) * 2) + 5)))

rng.clearcontents
```

Comment: I tried something similar, not exactly the same. I'm away from the office but will try it ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for that, the exact lines used are: